# Name two abelian groups of order 54 that are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra

One abelian group of order 54 would of course be the cyclic group.

I am totally lost in thinking of another one

Comment: Call $C_{27}\times C_2$ *Juan* and call $C_{3} \times C_9\times C_2$ *Carlos*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers with $\gcd(m,n)>1$, then $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

$54=2\times 3^3$.

So for example the following groups are not isomorphic:

$\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_3$ and $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_{27}$.

The one on the right is cyclic. There is one more, can you find it? Also, you may want to re-read the fundamental theorem for finite abelian groups.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a cyclic group of order $54$, then isomorphically, we have $\mathbb{Z}_{54}$

Now we want to find another group of order $54$, but is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{54}$. The easiest way to create a group that is not cyclic, we can consider the decomposition of $\mathbb{Z}_{54}$ as a possible external direct product of cyclic groups of prime-power orders. One such example is:
$$\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$$

This is not cyclic since gcd(3, 3) is not 1. So it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{54}$, but $2 \cdot 3^3 = 54$, so it has order $54$ as desired.